# Red Exclamation Mark appeared when I add google play services lib

Tags: android, google-play-services, buildpath

[image]I am using GCM in my project for push notifiaction, but when I added google play service library into my project after importing this, A red exclamation mark appeared in my project, I already have seen different question and answers regarding this problem when I saw my build path of project there is cross sign on Android dependencies folder please help me,[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to import the whole google play project and use it as a library project for your own project, not just the jar. Try [Google's guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) again.

Check to see if your google play lib looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I already tried this guide from this guide Copy the library project at <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects. I did the same

Comment: Then try rebuild google play project, the jar was probably somehow cleared.

Comment: Look I think there is might be a confusion between both of us, Actually I created a project which named as pushnotification, then I Copy the library project at <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services‌​_lib/ this file at my documents and import this library to eclispe and then I add this library to my push notification project by going into this properties->Android->Add, and set both to 4.2 sdk,, Is this right way ?

Comment: @Shazar your Google Play proj's /bin dir is empty, so your project cannot find the .jar file. Have you tried Project -> Clean on Google Play proj?

Comment: Yes i tried , And now sign disappered but when I going run the projects it said android project cannot be launched is this the same problem?

Comment: okk Now it get fixed I uncheck the is library option by going to propertied-> android>uncheck "is library"

Answer (score 0):

That means the jar is not available in bin directory...check manually that the jar is available or not in that directory..

Comment: I checked and its available